# Flexbox alignment in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Please see this fiddle where the layout works well in chrome, firefox but not Safari..

html..

```
<div class="row flex-at-desktop">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><!--col1-->
<img src="http://2cousins.designbankdevelopment.co.uk/wp-content/themes/shapely/images/2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>                  

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><!--col2-->
<div class="something-semantic">
<div class="something-else-semantic">
<p>my text</p>                      
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div><!--end of row-->
```

css..

```
.flex-at-desktop {
display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex;
}
.something-semantic {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height:100%
}
.something-else-semantic {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
background:#ccc
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3me544L3/1/

The aim is to have the column with the text in match the height of the image in the other column, and once that happens - to align the text vertically in the div. This is working well in some browsers but in Safari the div doesnt adapt to  full height?

Comment: may be it will not work with windows safari did you check with Mac ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I'm on safari on a mac currently

Comment: question improved hopefully

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276